# Correct way to do a Thomas-Fermi approximation for cold gases

Tags: quantum-mechanics, bose-einstein-condensate, cold-atoms

I have calculated the total Gross-Pitaevskii energy for a 2D Bose-Einstein condensate in an harmonical trap, using a variational gaussian wave function with a variational parameter *b*. Now I want to compare the variational energy to the Thomas-Fermi result. 
I know that the Thomas-Fermi approximation means that you neglect the total kinetic energy in comparison to the interaction energy, but I was wondering how to do it specifically in this case. I namely have three different possibilities in mind:

1) Just remove the kinetic energy term from the energy expression I found with the variational wave function, and keep the value of the variational parameter *b* as it was before.

2) Remove the kinetic energy term from the energy expression I found with the variational wave function, and calculate a new value for the variational parameter *b* for this specific case.

3) Use the Thomas-Fermi approximation in the GP equation to find a new expression for the wave function (instead of the one I used before) and use this one to calculate the energy.

I can't seem to decide which of these three is the right one. Can anyone give a convincing argument as to which method I should use?

Answer (score 1):

You simply take $|\psi|^2=1/g[\mu-V(x)]$.

This because now your time independent GPE is

$\mu\psi=(V+g|\psi|^2)\psi$